# Dated jboss console log entries

Tags: jboss

Currently my jboss's console log entries are not dated, 
If the log is timely dated with time which will help me to debug some application performance issue.
Can any one give some tips on the same?

Comment: Add the contents of `conf/jboss-log4j.xml`to your question, and tell us which version of JBoss you're using.

Comment: V- jboss-3.2.7 , and I cant find any entry related to consolelog in log4j.

Answer (score 0):

The log configuration in JBoss 3.2.7 exists in the `log4j.xml` file. You can find that file in the `conf` directory of given configuration.

You can find there such lines:

```
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>

     <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
      -->
  </layout>
```

You can just simple comment first definition of `ConversionPattern` and uncomment the second one. Or just simple create your own conversion pattern, you can find more about it here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html